# jquery to truncate a selected value of select list

Tags: jquery

I have a select list value that I want to truncate the value.

Here is the value of the select list: `Spanish (Spain) - español (España)‎`

I want to cut off text so that only the text before the hyphen is displayed, like so: `Spanish (Spain)`

Here is my jquery:

```
var newLanguageName = $( "#id_language_code option:selected" ).text();
```

How would I do this? I have googled and searched and tried trim, but I cannot get this to work.

Comment: Just edited my answer to include 3 options to get what you want, check it out :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `split` .

```
var newLanguageName = $("#id_language_code option:selected" ).text().split('-')[0];
```

and for `trim`:

```
var newLanguageName = $.trim($( "#id_language_code option:selected" ).text().split('-')[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the initial string you have several options:

```
var newLanguageName = $( "#id_language_code option:selected" ).text();
```

**Option 1** A combination of `substring()` and `indexOf()`:

```
var trimmed = newLanguageName.substring(0, newLanguageName.indexOf('-'));
```

**Option 2** Use `split()`

```
var trimmed = newLanguageName.split('-')[0]
```

**Option 3** Use `regex`

```
var trimmed = newLanguageName.match(/[^-]*/i)[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the javascript command `.substring(...)`
Description of substring: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp
 With `.indexOf(...)` (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) you can find the position of the - separator.

Comment: This is not an answer - there are already answers using substring and indexOf and w3schools is a very poor reference. If you want to earn rep, answer with code examples.

Comment: As i begun to write my answer, it has no answer here :-(

Comment: So show how to use indexOf and substring instead of linking to a crap site?